# When replacing value in a string array I get an array when using " " but not with ' '

Tags: c

In my code I am trying to replace a value in a string.

When I do the replacement with double quotes

```
input[n]="\n";
```

I get a

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         input[n]="\n";
                 ^
```

However if I use single quotes

```
input[n]='\n'
```

it works.

Comment: Warning itself is clear! `"\n"` is `char *` where as `'\n'` is `char`.

Comment: In C, single quotes and double quotes serve a _different_ purpose. The former denotes a character while the latter denotes a string.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike python, in C `''` and `""` are not interchangeable. C considers single quotes `''` as a single character, while double quotes `""` are for strings of characters, your variable input is probably either a `char*` or `char[xx]` so each element is a single character, so a single quote `''` is what you should use.

Answer (score 3):

In `c` the difference between single and double quotes has semantic meaning. Single quote indicates a char value and double quotes indicates string literal. The warning you get is indicative of this.

Answer (score 0):

Single are use for char and double quotes are for string.